# FreeBSD pf Egress Filtering

Tags: freebsd, openbsd, pf

I am attempting to build a simple pf.conf which includes NAT allowing traffic out of the network from all systems on a select series of ports. In my basic configuration I have an internal server that hosts HTTP/HTTPS which will be accessible from the outside via the NATed IP. From the inside I would only like clients to leave the network on DNS/HTTP/HTTPS.

```
int_if="eth0"
ext_if="eth1"
localnet=$int_if:network

nat on $ext_if from $localnet to any -> ($ext_if)
comp1="172.16.0.1"
rdr on $ext_if proto tcp from any -> $comp1 port http
rdr on $ext_if proto tcp from any -> $comp1 port https

client_out_tcp = "{ http, https}"
client_out_udp = "{ 53 }"
pass inet proto tcp from $localnet to port $client_out_tcp
pass inet proto tcp from $localnet to port $client_out_udp
```

With this configuration my server is contacted on the proper ports as I designed however my clients can always leave the network no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you don't block outgoing traffic by default on your localnet.

Try using something along those lines:

```
block out from $localnet to any
pass inet proto tcp from $localnet to port $client_out_tcp
pass inet proto tcp from $localnet to port $client_out_udp
```